# Geolocalización openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Buenas tardes me gustaría hacer que el mapa de `openlayers` tome mi posición actual y muestre un circulo, pero al intentarlo no me sale nada. No se que puedo estar haciendo mal.

Estoy tomando como ejemplo el código del siguiente link y he adaptado un poco el código, pero como no me tira error no se que puedo estar fallando https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geolocation.html

Si alguien puede ayudarme a sacar esto se lo agradecería mucho ya que me esta dando dolor de cabezas porque soy nuevo en el tema. Saludos y desde ya muchas gracias

```
    var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  //  source: new ol.source.OSM()
       'title': 'Google Maps Uydu',
       'type': 'base',
        visible: true,
       'opacity': 1.000000,
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        attributions: [new ol.Attribution({ html: '<a href=""></a>' })],
        url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@113&hl=en&&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}'
        })
  });

  var view = new ol.View({
      projection: 'EPSG:4326',
         center:[longitud, latitud],
                // [0, 0], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                    zoom: 13,
                   minZoom: 1,
                   maxZoom: 24
  });
  var map = new ol.Map({
      loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    layers: [layer],
    view: view,
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
          zoom: true,     
          attributionOptions: {
           collapsible: false           
           }
         }),
  });

  var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
      // enableHighAccuracy must be set to true to have the heading value.
      trackingOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
      },
      projection: view.getProjection()
    });

    geolocation.setTracking(this.checked);
    var accuracyFeature = new ol.Feature();
    geolocation.on('change:accuracyGeometry', function() {
      accuracyFeature.setGeometry(geolocation.getAccuracyGeometry());
   });

    var positionFeatureCirculo = new ol.Feature();
    positionFeatureCirculo.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 6,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: '#3399CC'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#fff',
          width: 2
        })
      })
    }));

    geolocation.on('change:position', function() {
      var coordinates = geolocation.getPosition();
      positionFeatureCirculo.setGeometry(coordinates ?
        new ol.Point(coordinates) : null);
   });

    new ol.layer.VectorLayer({
      map: map,
      source: new VectorSource({
        features: [accuracyFeature, positionFeature]
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta activarlo...

```
var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
      **tracking: true,**
      // enableHighAccuracy must be set to true to have the heading value.
      trackingOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
      },
      projection: view.getProjection()
    });
```